# NLog render HttpContext.Request.TotalBytes

Tags: asp.net, nlog

Is it possible to render the `HttpContext.Request.TotalBytes` value directly in NLog configuration? I know this won't work but something along the lines or this:

```xml
<parameter name="@TotalBytes" layout="${aspnet-request:totalbytes}" />
```

Comment: ASP.net or ASP.net core?

Comment: just regular ASP.net

Answer (score 0):

You can easily extend NLog with custom layout renderers.

In this case, register before logging:

```cs
//register ${aspnet-request-totalbytes}
LayoutRenderer.Register("aspnet-request-totalbytes", (logEvent) => 
                         HttpContext.Request.TotalBytes.ToString());
```

and use in your config: `${aspnet-request-totalbytes}`

note: colon isn't allowed in custom layout renderer name

NLog 4.4+ needed

for more info, [see the NLog wiki](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Extending-NLog)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I got pulled off in another direction. But hopefully I can circle back and apply this technique. Thanks for following up!